# Host resolution with docker and docker-compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I'm wondering why, with docker-compose, the container cannot resole host-name while it's working with docker ?  The host is on different physical machine but on the same network.

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
CMD ping -c 2 myhost
```

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    net:
        build: .
        image: test/myimage:1.0
        container_name: mycontainer
```

After a `docker-compose build` I tried

```
docker run -it test/myimage:1.0
PING myhost (10.20.78.13): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.20.78.13: seq=0 ttl=250 time=0.720 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.78.13: seq=1 ttl=250 time=0.515 ms
```

but

```
docker-compose up
Recreating mycontainer ...
Recreating mycontainer ... done
Attaching to mycontainer
mycontainer | ping: bad address 'myhost'
mycontainer exited with code 1
```

What can I do to have it working ?

Edit1

Using `cat /etc/resolv.conf` instead of `ping -c 2 myhost`

```
docker-compose up
Recreating mycontainer ...
Recreating mycontainer ... done
Attaching to mycontainer
mycontainer | search myorg.intra
mycontainer | nameserver 127.0.0.11
mycontainer | options ndots:0
mycontainer exited with code 0
```

and

```
docker run -it test/myimage:1.0
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.19.128.55
nameserver 10.19.142.23
nameserver 10.19.128.56
search myorg.intra
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use the dns entries in your compose also

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    net:
        build: .
        image: test/myimage:1.0
        container_name: mycontainer
        dns:
          - 10.19.128.55
          - 10.19.142.23
          - 10.19.128.56
        dns_search: myorg.intra
```

If you don't want to specify them per container then you can even set them directly at the daemon level.

Create or edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and below entries in the JSON file

```
{
    "dns": ["10.19.128.55", "10.19.142.23", "10.19.128.56"],
    "dns-search": ["myorg.intra"],
}
```

Restart the docker service using `service docker restart`. Then you should not need the entries in the `docker-compose`. Your original `docker-compose` should work

Comment: Thanks.  I already found that solution and it's working except for the dns-search.  I don't understand why.  A ping on myhost.myorg.intra is working fine but not on myhost.

Comment: Can you check how your `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is coming up inside the container?

Comment: Rrrr... docker is going to make me mad.  I removed the deamon.json file to try with the docker-compose.yml, restarted docker, restarted the machine, removed the container, the image, the network and ... it is still working with myhost.myorg.intra

Comment: Try `docker-compose rm -f -v`. If that doesn't work, try to Kill all running containers, `docker system prune -a`, this clear everything. Even images.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle difference in network settings when running docker commands directly vs. performing some docker-compose runs. With docker-compose the containers are attached to some user-defined network which is a `bridged network` but not with the same configuration as the `default bridged network`. The latter one does some special configuration to be backwards compatible to the versions where these networking features didn't exist like today.

I assume that when running from compose, you are missing some dns settings that are available on your host machine and thus you aren't able to resolve the other host on your network. Please have a look at the differences [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) and [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/). For a first check, you could compare the output when running `cat /etc/resolv.conf` instead of your ping command for both ways and see what you need to add to make it work from compose.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas.  I edited my question.  So I now see that with compose the dns is 127.0.0.11 but what can I do ?  Do I have to add the name servers of my host ?  But in that case the container is tied up with my machine and is no more portable.